# ヘルプ日本語訳:Communityユーザーが質問を削除する基準

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

最近追加されたヘルプですが、英語のままなので日本語に訳します。

本家 [The Community user deleted my question! What gives?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)
日本語版（予定地） https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba

数日様子を見て、問題なさそうならjmacさんに反映をお願いする予定です。誤訳等あれば編集もしくはコメントしていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 2):

タイトル: 私の質問がCommunityユーザーに削除されたのはなぜですか？

---

[Communityユーザー](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)は次の条件を満たした古い質問を自動的に削除します。

**`30` 日以上前に投稿された質問で、かつ...**

- スコアが -1 以下
- 回答がついていない
- ロックされていない

もしくは

- 別のサイトに移動された

ものは dead question として削除され、`RemoveDeadQuestions` もしくは `RemoveMigrationStubs` （別サイトへ移動された場合）と表記されます。

**`365` 日以上前に投稿された質問で、かつ...**

- スコアが 0 以下（質問したユーザーが既に存在しない場合は 1 以下）
- 回答がついていない
- ロックされていない
- 質問の閲覧数 <= 質問が投稿されてからの日数 * 1.5
- 質問に対するコメントが 1 件以下

ものは abandoned question として削除され、 `RemoveAbandonedQuestions` と表記されます。

これらのチェックは毎週行われます。

**`9` 日以上前にクローズされた質問で、かつ...**

- クローズ理由が「重複」ではない
- スコアが 0 以下
- ロックされていない
- スコア 1 以上の回答がついていない
- 承認済みの回答がない
- 再オープン票が入っていない
- 過去 9 日間に編集されていない

ものは abandoned closed として削除され、 `RemoveAbandonedClosed` と表記されます。

このチェックは毎日行われます。

投稿の削除に関する仕様については、メタSEのFAQ ["How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) もご覧ください。