# 「Communityユーザーが質問を削除する基準」 は 質問についてのカテゴリにいるべきではないでしょうか。

Tags: 機能の要求, ヘルプ

[ヘルプ日本語訳:Communityユーザーが質問を削除する基準](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2211/754) のヘルプについてです。

これは今、「ヘルプセンター -> 弊社のモデル」の下に登録されていますが、「ヘルプセンター -> 質問について」の下に登録されている方が自然だし、探しやすい気がします。

当ヘルプ: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba

Comment: これは全サイトに統一していますので、場所について聞いてみます。とりあえずこれは「バグ」より「機能の要求」だと思いますので、タグを編集させていただきます。

Comment: バッジとかメタとか、システム面での仕様もここに入っているので、それでCommunityによる自動削除もここに配置された気はします。