# ヘルプページ「私の質問がCommunityユーザーに削除されたのはなぜですか？」を改善したい

Tags: サポート, 翻訳, ヘルプ, 質問の削除

ヘルプセンター > 私たちのモデル
[私の質問がCommunityユーザーに削除されたのはなぜですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) の翻訳案です。

約 6 年前に [@unarist さんが翻訳くださったもの](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2211/14055)を元に、これまでに変更がかかった部分を改善できればとおもいます。変更に気付かれた箇所や改善案がありましたら直接編集またはコメントで指摘をお願いいたします。参考となる英語版は[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)です。

---

### 私の質問がコミュニティ♦︎ユーザーに削除されたのはなぜですか？

[コミュニティ♦︎ユーザー](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1418/14055)は次の条件を満たした古い質問を自動的に削除します。

**`30` 日以上前に投稿された質問で、かつ...**

- スコアが -1 以下
- 回答がついていない
- ロックされていない

もしくは

- 別のサイトに移動された

ものは dead question として削除され、`RemoveDeadQuestions` もしくは `RemoveMigrationStubs` （別サイトへ移動された場合）と表記されます。

**`365` 日以上前に投稿された質問で、かつ...**

- スコアが 0 以下（質問したユーザーが既に存在しない場合は 1 以下）
- 回答がついていない
- ロックされていない
- 質問の閲覧数 <= 質問が投稿されてからの日数 * 1.5
- 質問に対するコメントが 1 件以下

ものは abandoned question として削除され、 `RemoveAbandonedQuestions` と表記されます。

これらのチェックは毎週行われます。

**`9` 日以上前にクローズされた質問で、かつ...**

- クローズ理由が「重複」ではない
- スコアが 0 以下
- ロックされていない
- スコア 1 以上の回答がついていない
- 承認済みの回答がない
- 再オープン票が入っていない
- 過去 9 日間に編集されていない

ものは abandoned closed として削除され、 `RemoveAbandonedClosed` と表記されます。

このチェックは毎日行われます。

投稿の削除に関する仕様については、メタのよくある質問 [「投稿が削除される仕組みを教えてください」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2869/14055) もご覧ください。

Comment: FYI, I recently edited this Help Center page to remove the code formatting (and the mentions of the deletion reasons used in the code), following [this MSE request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314188/335251). I also made the corresponding changes to the translated versions of the Help Center page for our international sites, including SOja.